# Why query idle for months in pg_stat_activity?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to alter a table named order and it blocked. Then I found something weird in `pg_stat_activity`:

```
ss> select *  from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'ss' and query ilike 'delete%order%'
-[ RECORD 0 ]-------------------------
datid            | 80874
datname          | ss
pid              | 24349
usesysid         | 16384
usename          | user
application_name |
client_addr      | 172.17.0.1
client_hostname  | <null>
client_port      | 54008
backend_start    | 2017-09-26 09:36:46.928444+08
xact_start       | <null>
query_start      | 2017-09-26 10:29:26.337025+08
state_change     | 2017-09-26 10:29:26.352698+08
waiting          | False
state            | idle
backend_xid      | <null>
backend_xmin     | <null>
query            | DELETE FROM order WHERE order_id = '20180948464423'
```

this query idled for 3 months and I checked the process 24349 do exists. And I found the deleting was success.

So why this query last for so long? How to reproduce it? Is it a bug?
And is it blocking my ddl on that table?

Comment: If a session is "idle" the query you see is the _last_ query it executed. It is not currently executing (then the state would be "active"). But a session that is "idle" should not block an `alter table`. Are you sure it was _that_ session that was blocking your DDL? A session that is "idle in transaction" would do that, but not one that is "idle"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know what you mean. But I think there is not any session that last for 3 months. The client ip is 172.17.0.1, I think it's one of our app docker containers. But the most long-term container lasts only six days (It's development environment).

Comment: it does not matter how long the session lasts - it will last till the disconnect. its normal. idle sessions can't block - only `idle in transaction` or obviously `active`